# One of my project subdirectories has disappeared from Eclipse PHP Explorer and refuses to reappear

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

The subfolder myproject/wp-content has dissapeared from the project explorer (of course the files are still there, I can see them on windows explorer).

All the other folders and files are still showing up.

I tried deleting the project files (.settings .buildpath .project) and deleting the project on eclipse and also deleting the index on .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2

What else can I do?

I'm using stock Eclipse Kepler 4.3.1 SR1 64-bit with the following add-ons:

```
  Aptana Studio 3 Plugin    3.4.2.201308081736-7W7I57boG98RAi489ctbvKi7VXbq com.aptana.feature.studio.feature.group Aptana
  ChromeDevTools SDK    0.3.9.201309080643  org.chromium.sdk.feature.group  The Chromium Authors
  Chromium JavaScript Remote Debugger   0.3.9.201309080643  org.chromium.debug.feature.group    The Chromium Authors
  Eclipse Standard/SDK  2.0.1.20130919-0803 epp.package.standard    null
  Line Number Ruler Fix (Eclipse Kepler 4.3)    0.0.1   de.cdhq.eclipse.linenumberfix.kepler.feature.feature.group  CDHQ.de
  Markdown Editor   0.2.3   markdown.editor.feature.feature.group   Winterwell
  Nodeclipse    0.5.0.201309080643  org.nodeclipse.feature.group    Nodeclipse organization
  PHP Development Tools (PDT)   3.2.0.201306051924  org.eclipse.php.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Show Window in Fullscreen 1.1.0.200906152252  gr.scharf.fullscreen_feature.feature.group  Michael Scharf http://michaelscharf.blogspot.com/
  Word Wrap Feature 0.0.3   de.cdhq.eclipse.wordwrap.feature.feature.group  CDHQ.de
```

**[EDIT]** I forgot to mention I've also tried to rebuild the project with the same results, and I've also checked explorer view filters in case something weird had happened but there are no filters set.

**[EDIT 2]** I deleted the Eclipse project files and the whole .metadata folder on the workspace and recreated the project. I had no problem at first, but it has happened again. I haven't touch any settings, just closed and reopened the project.

**[EDIT 3]** The less invasive fix by now seems to be a combination of deleting h2 database (.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2 workspace folder) and deleting also the project without deleting its files which doesn't delete .build or .settings or .buildpath either, so it can be recreated without much hussle. I can avoid the problem by not closing the project (I can still close Eclipse without loosing the folder), but I still don't know what's causing it.

**[EDIT 4]** I updated Eclipse and plugins today to their latest versions (Now runnning Kepler 4.3.2) and the problem persists (even if I delete org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2 and .settings, .buildpath, .project before importing the project's folder contents as a new project): I just close the project after eclipse finishes indexing it and when I reopen it wp-content doesn't show up any more (unless I force reindexing by deleting org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2 again). I do believe this is WordPress related, since it only happens when indexing this particular WordPress deployment (maybe it's one of the plugins/theme files installed inside wp-content or something related to one of the xml files in the root folder, like sitemap.xml?).

Comment: Do the files still appear in the Navigator View? Can you add an image showing where it should be?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a .gitignore file that the IDE is obeying?

Comment: nope and nope. I've tried everything and ended up deleting the whole .metadata folder and rebuilding the entire workspace, so I'll just delete the question.

Comment: Mark the project in the project explorer and press f5. It usually works. Maybe its just out of sync

Comment: It has happened again! After deleting the whole workspace and Eclipse project files and recreating the project I couldn't see the folder again (@The D Merged I tried F5 but no luck). I worked for a few hours, then some more this morning. I closed the project (didn't open any other projects or close  eclipse), reopened it and wp-content folder was gone (I mean not deleted, but it doesn't show up in the project explorer). I lost all my workspace settings for nothing. What is happening?¿?!

Comment: Try a File Search for mentions of its name, and turning off any Filters that may be enabled in the view.

Comment: Like I've mentioned: No filters at all are set. It worked fine until just a couple of days ago, and I didn't change anything at all on my settings or even added new files to the project. A search for the folder or any files in it returns nothing but references on other files outside the folder. I've localized the fix to deleting the project (which doesn't delete .settings, .buildpath or .project, so that's cool) and .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2 folder and the problem triggers only if I close the project (I can close Eclipse without problem). This is all really weird.

Comment: Is there any library missing in your project, which was originally refered earlier and not available in your project library folder any more??

Comment: nope, I don't think so. But I did remove a bunched of zipped backups from the project folder. Anyway after recreating the project from scratch that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

For me this happened multiple times, on different project and different folders. Opening+closing or refreshing the project yield no success.

In my case, I have found out that this is related to the Working sets. It seems by default new subfolders and files of a project are not marked belonging to the set, so the project has a mix of old folders (included) and new folders (excluded).

There are two fixes I am aware of:

- disable the working sets

  Moreover, on large projects, having this mixed state working set made opening the folder structure (and other operations) very slow (3-5 seconds per level). Turning off the working set filter made it instantaneous.
- edit the active working set and check the project's checkbox (which will check all subfolders).

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me all the time. I'm on OSX and my projects are accessed from a mounted samba volume. I've found that if I:

- open the project in eclipse
- eject the samba volume
- refresh the project (it will say it cant find it and ask if you want to delete
  it... click no)
- remount the samba volume
- refresh the eclipse project

And the missing files/folders show up. If your folders are local, maybe just moving the project folder would do the same. Unfortunately, this happens very often, and seemingly more often for wordpress projects for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with a UI project (Dynamic Web Project) and my web folder keeps dissapearing too. I didn't knew what causes that.

The only thing I knew was how to reset my projet; deleting it from workpsace and reimporting it.

I know now what causes that but I have no answer on why it actually does it. I keep refreshing my workspace because I have some compressing that is done outside eclipse and for my workspace to update them I need to refresh... somehow, the freaking Close Project option is right under the Refresh option, without prompting... and this is when my folder dissapear; when I reopen it.

Try the Import Existing Project would be my guess!

Maybe that can help you find the how of it !

Comment: It's a local folder and it happens every time I close the project. As I've mentioned the best I can do to fix it is deleting the h2 database and the project. Moving the folder does not help, unfortunately. Anyway, I've switched to PHPStorm, and I'm much much happier now. Eclipse, PDT and Aptana plugin are both amazing projects, though. I've worked with them for years with very few issues, a truckload of features and reasonable performance. That's why I plan to donate the same amount I spent on PHPStorm to keep them going (Also I hate buying software without getting the code... Not so InteliJ.)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i solve this problem by unchecking "Group by Namespaces" in the little triangle on the top-right of the php explorer.

Comment: Didn't work. (It was never checked to begin with :-( )

Answer (score 1):

Issue:

My app directory in my cake php application became invisible after some time.  This is bad since all of my non-cakephp framework files reside therein!

My environment:
Macosx
Eclipse Kepler
WebServer: built in macosx in Library/WebServer/Documents which is symlinked to a dir in my home directory.
PHP plugin

What I tried first:
Deleted old project from UI ( retaining files on the file system )
cd'ed to root project directory and deleted eclipse artifacts like .settings, .project, etc
Recreated php project to find that the app directory is still missing!

What worked for me:
I renamed the directory from app to app_back using the terminal/linux command rn. 
Eclipse immediate saw the new dir after a clean rebuild.
I renamed the dir back to app and performed another clean rebuild.
Et Voila

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work either. The folder reappears, yes, but as soon as as I close and reopen the project it's missing again, so no improvement at all (I even copied the entire folder to a dedicated workspace with the same results). Anyway, what did work was upgrading Eclipse to last version (Luna), removing the project files (.settings, .classpath and .project) and creating a new project on a new workspace. Now I can close and reopen the project as many times as I want :-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by upgrading Eclipse to last version (Luna), removing the project files (.settings, .classpath and .project) and creating a new project on a new workspace, I can close and reopen the project without having the folder missing from the project explorer.

It's not the solution I wanted (and don't need any more) but it's also a solution, so I'm posting it :-)